# Uploaded my entire computer User directory to Github. How can I stop it

Tags: github, synchronization, addition

I stuffed up on Github in my first 5 min.
Tried to setup a sync folder and accidentaly syncronized my entire user folder 85Gb!

Q) How do I stop it from syncronising that folder and change it to a subfolder?
(I think I also need to remove all those files from Github :-)

I used "add ."
Not "commit"
checked using Git Gui
"Disk space used by loose objects 6641381 KiB"

Thanks in advance
James

I'm afraid to try anything else as I might delete both the upload and what is on my computer as itv is syncronised!

Answer (score 0):

If you just `git Add .` instead of `git commit` , you can type this command:

```
git reset
```